# Improve sort performance in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index

I've got a simple blog database in postgres-8.4 which has two tables, `articles` and `comments`. I have a query (generated by Django) that wants to get the latest article of type 'NEWS' and also find the number of comments for that article. It does that with the following query:

```
SELECT "articles"."id", "articles"."datestamp", "articles"."title", "articles"."shorttitle", "articles"."description", "articles"."markdown", "articles"."body", "articles"."idxfti", "articles"."published", "articles"."type", COUNT("comments"."id") AS "comment__count"
FROM "articles"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON ("articles"."id" = "comments"."article_id")
WHERE ("articles"."type"='NEWS')
GROUP BY "articles"."id", "articles"."datestamp", "articles"."title", "articles"."shorttitle", "articles"."description", "articles"."markdown", "articles"."body", "articles"."idxfti", "articles"."published", "articles"."type"
ORDER BY "articles"."datestamp" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

None of these tables is particularly large, and yet that query takes 46ms. The execution plan is:

```
Limit  (cost=119.54..119.58 rows=1 width=1150) (actual time=46.479..46.481 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=119.54..138.88 rows=455 width=1150) (actual time=46.475..46.475 rows=1 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=119.54..120.68 rows=455 width=1150) (actual time=46.426..46.428 rows=2 loops=1)
           Sort Key: articles.datestamp, articles.id, articles.title, articles.shorttitle, articles.description, articles.markdown, articles.body, articles.idxfti, articles.published, articles.type
           Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 876kB
           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=11.34..99.45 rows=455 width=1150) (actual time=0.513..2.527 rows=566 loops=1)
                 Hash Cond: (articles.id = comments.article_id)
                 ->  Seq Scan on articles  (cost=0.00..78.84 rows=455 width=1146) (actual time=0.017..0.881 rows=455 loops=1)
                       Filter: ((type)::text = 'NEWS'::text)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=8.93..8.93 rows=193 width=8) (actual time=0.486..0.486 rows=193 loops=1)
                       ->  Seq Scan on comments  (cost=0.00..8.93 rows=193 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.252 rows=193 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 46.574 ms
```

The articles table has the following index defined (amongst others):

```
idx_articles_datestamp" btree (datestamp DESC) CLUSTER
```

Before I clustered it, the query execution was more in line with the estimates, around 119ms.

To my untrained eye, it looks like the sort is what's taking the most amount of time here. It also seems to be trying to sort on all the GROUP BY fields, the issue being that it's trying to sort on three relatively large fields, `body`, `markdown` and `idx_fti`.

My question is this: Is this an unreasonable amount of time for this query to take, or is there something obvious I've missed that I can use to speed this query up? All the other queries requested by this blog site take around 1-5ms to execute, so this one stands out as taking a long time. I appreciate there's an OUTER JOIN and a SORT, which don't really help. However, I'm not an expert, so if anyone has any suggestions, that'd be hugely useful.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to rewrite the query, with an inline subquery:

```
SELECT id,
       datestamp,
       title,
       shorttitle,
       description,
       markdown,
       body,
       idxfti,
       published,
       type,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM comments 
         WHERE articles.id = comments.article_id
       ) AS comment__count
FROM articles 
WHERE type = 'NEWS'
ORDER BY datestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 This should be the best solution. In connection with an index on `comments(article)` and the above mentioned index on `articles(type, datestamp DESC)`. The query uses `LIMIT 1`, so only relevant rows should be fetched from `article` and counted.

Comment: +1 Postgres optimizer deals greatly with this type of query, inline aggregation query in combination with a sorted parent node

Answer (score 9):

#### Why is it slow?

I would advise to use the [query @ypercube provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17214/3684) in combination with the mentioned indexes. But ***why*** is the query you had so slow in comparison?

You did not provide your table definition, but I assume from the column names and what you wrote that you have several (large) character type (`text` or `varchar`) columns in the table `articles`:

```
title, shorttitle, description, markdown, body, idx_fti
```

I further assume that you are running your database with a [locale other than `C`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html). **Sorting large text columns according to a locale is rather expensive.** The relevant thing is the **collation**. Check your (current) setting for `LC_COLLATE`:

```
SHOW LC_COLLATE;
```

With Postgres 9.1 or later you can [pick a collation for evaluating your expressions ad hoc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html). With PostgreSQL **8.4**, however, this is set at cluster creation time and can't be changed later.

We recently had a related question on SO where after much deliberation and testing we found sorting according to a locale to be the major slowdown:

- [Slow query ordering by a column in a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888096/slow-query-ordering-by-a-column-in-a-joined-table/9908333#9908333)

I expect @ypercube's query to solve that problem radically: No `GROUP BY` for the long text columns eliminates the expensive sort altogether. Problem solved.

Comment: could you please help me out in a similar question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818667/improve-postgressql-aggregation-query-performance

Answer (score 3):

If articles.type is less than about 10% of the table, you might benefit from an index on that column.  You can almost certainly benefit from an index on comments.article_id, if you don't already have one.

In addition to that, if you haven't adjusted the cost factors in your configuration, you could try lowering `random_page_cost` to somewhere in the 1.0 to 2.0 range; if your active data set is fully cached, you should probably take that *and* `seq_page_cost` down to 0.1.  You should probably increase `cpu_tuple_cost` to somewhere in the range of 0.03 to 0.05.  `effective_cache_size` should be the sum of `shared_buffers` and whatever your OS shows as cache space.

Comment: I did already have an index on `comments.article_id`, and adding one to `articles.type` didn't seem to do a lot. I'll try tweaking some of the server settings though, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try to remove the group by and use a windowing function for counting. That removes the need to group by/sort on all columns:

```
SELECT articles.id,
       articles.datestamp,
       articles.title,
       articles.shorttitle,
       articles.description,
       articles.markdown,
       articles.body,
       articles.idxfti,
       articles.published,
       articles.type,
       COUNT(comments.id) over () AS comment__count
FROM articles 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (articles.id = comments.article_id)
WHERE (articles.type = 'NEWS')
ORDER BY articles.datestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: An index on `(type ASC, datestamp DESC)` would additionally improve performance, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ypercube: yes, might very well help as well to speed up the where condition.

Comment: Yeah, if the query can be rewritten, there are a number of good alternatives, of which this might well be the best.  Even more options exist on version 9.1, where if you `GROUP BY` the primary key column(s) you don't need to include any of the other columns from that table.

Comment: I tried adding an index with `create index idx_articles_type_datestamp on articles(type ASC, datestamp DESC)` but that didn't seem to make much difference. I'll see what I can do with forcing django to do a `COUNT OVER`, but am I right in thinking that's Pg-specific?

Comment: @growse: windowing functions are standard SQL and supported by a lot of modern DBMS (Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server, Teradata, Firebird 3.0)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could do some tests modifying the value of [work_mem](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM). There you can find instructions in order to find how much memory is used in the sorting operations.

Comment: When a sort does not fit into work_mem, it spills out to the disk.  If happens, this is shown in the query plan.  On the other hand, the sorting here took 876 kB of memory.  It is very unlikely that this is bigger than the work_mem of any relatively recent PG instances.